# Passing a variable name to a dplyr function within another function returns object not found error

Tags: r, function, dplyr

When passing a variable name within a function to another function which has some dplyr code,
I get a object not found error message. This only happens when I try to pass the variable name within a function, I can run the the dplyr function directly without problems.

```
library(dplyr)

fun_1 <- function(data, var){
  return(data %>%  
           summarise(mean = mean ({{var}}))
        )
 }

 
fun_2 <- function(data, var){
  output <- fun_1(data = data,
                  var = var)
  return(output)
}
```

Running the first function directly works fine, but when trying to pass a variable name within another function to dpylr I get an error message.

```
fun_1(iris, Sepal.Length)
      mean
1 5.843333


fun_2(iris, Sepal.Length)

Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `mean`.
i `mean = mean(var)`.
x object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

I try to unterstand why this happens and how I can pass data and variable names to a dyplr function within a function.

Comment: I think you need `fun_1(data = data, var = {{ var }})` inside `fun_2`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve this problem. However, if doing so I can only use the variable with dplyr, but not access it in a "normal" R fashion? For example to extract the name of the variable `deparse(substitute(var)` within fun_1?

Comment: Non-standard evaluation is "cool" when it works but rife with many risks; when it fails, its errors can be rather obtuse and confusing. If you really want to work on this, then you should as a start read through http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ (in which this is discussed).

Comment: I mean, you can use names other than `var`. You can have `var1`, `var2`, `var3` or `grouping_col`, `mean_col`, `sum_col`. Your functions are written for one variable, but you can write functions that accept multiple variables.

Comment: Yes, of course, it would make perfect sense to use more variables to pass the information needed. Thanks. My mind was kind of stuck with the, to me, obscure way of passing the variable. 
I've also looked in the Advanced R book for help/answers, but obviously I haven't quite grasped the whole concept of non-standard evaluation. I still have a lot of things to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a visibility issue. R has pretty complicated scoping rules. To ensure you're passing correctly specify the calls as follows:

```
fun_1(iris, iris$Sepal.Length)
fun_2(iris, iris$Sepal.Length)
```

Alternatively, just pass `var` as a string:

```
library(dplyr)

fun_1 <- function(data, var) {
  data %>% summarise(mean=mean(data[[var]]))
}

fun_2 <- function(data, var) {
  fun_1(data, var)
}

fun_1(iris, 'Sepal.Length')
fun_2(iris, 'Sepal.Length')
```

Comment: Thank you, both your suggestions work well as workarounds. If you want, you could even add Martin Gal's answer (in the comments) as a third solution to your answer so that we have all possible solutions in one answer.